# How to only render reflections on surface and keep the background transparent?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

I want to render a scene with a glossy object and a glossy floor plane and I want it to have a transparent background. I can do it without the reflections on the floor but when I try to add the reflections as well I either make the background black or I just can't get the reflection. How can I do this? I'm using Blender 3.1 and cycles.

Comment: are you sure you are in Cycles?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain

Comment: please show some screenshots

Comment: This video uses the Light Path Node from the shader editor to achieve reflections only. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wpi_GSx4X9M&ab_channel=ASAArt3d

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but here is a scene with 1 cube and 1 plane, both sharing the same metallic material. There is a HDRI background reflected in both the objects, as well as the cube's reflection on the plane. The background is transparent (due to the underlined checkbox) and the render looks the same as the viewport. Is this what you're looking for?

[image: Reflection]

Answer (score 0):

In general, glossy objects must have an environment to reflect or they won't look glossy.  Since you want a transparent background, the simplest way is to use an HDRI in the World Shader (Blender comes with eight of them, all [CC0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license#Zero_/_public_domain)):

[image]

The render must be saved in a format that can handle transparency, such as PNG with RGBA color.  And you said you're using Cycles, this also requires that you have Render Properties > Film > Transparent checked:

[image]

[image]